# Remove element from observableArray within Subscribe function without signalling it again

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

What I'm trying to do is the following:

```
var queueManagerClass = function() {

  this.queue = ko.observableArray();

    this.queue.subscribe( function(theChangedQueue) {
       // Do some nice things..

       // Nice things are over, remove the last item from the queue..
       this.queue.remove(theChangedQueue.pop());

    }.bind(this));
};
```

Except 2 problems occur: when I call this.queue.remove(item); I'll end up in an infinite loop.. The subscribe function will call it self over and over again..

I know there is an option to 'unbind' the subscribe function temporally but I can't risk the fact that I miss a queueItem that's inserted in the mean time of unbinding and binding again.

I hope you'll understand my (not so great..) english.

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to work around this is to make it detectable that you are in the process of removing the item and specifically ignore the event when that happens.  This can be done by using a local to store the "isRemoving" state.  For example

```
var isRemoving = false;
this.queue.subscribe( function(theChangedQueue) {
  if (isRemoving) {
    return;
  }

  // Do some nice things..

  // Nice things are over, remove the last item from the queue..
  isRemoving = true;
  this.queue.remove(theChangedQueue.pop());
  isRemoving = false;
}.bind(this));
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But one more thing: in your solution the subscribe function is simply returning when there's already been an element being removed from the array. This way, it's possible to miss subscribeEvents called from outside the subscribing function, right? Is there also a solution for this problem?

Comment: @NickGreen yes it is possible that if there are 2 subscribers who both remove in the subscribe function that you could possibly miss an event here

Comment: hmmm and there's no other solution for this?

Comment: @NickGreen so long as you remove in the changed event there is really no way to avoid this.  You could implement some counters to make sure you don't avoid other removes but I'm not sure you could verify you were only ignoring your remove

Comment: Oke thanks Jared, because you have the best (and only solution), and for explaining in the comments I'll accept your answer.. Thanks alot!